# Firefox/IE10 - HTML5 Application Cache and Cookies

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies, application-cache

I have a problem with HTML5 appCache on Firefox and IE10.

I have build a minimal test case available on:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7CVmRJOMgTNZUxkLWRDNmhtVU0/edit?usp=sharing

Accessing the page at "applicationCache/test.html" the browser will look for the correct manifest and will start to download all the content from the files in its list.

The problem occurs when I put in the list a .php file handling COOKIES; for example I have added a .php file which will call the php function "session_start()".
Chrome and Safari can handle correctly such file during the application cache download.
Firefox and IE10 share the behaviour: they halt and signal a generic error.

During a long search I found out this ticket on bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722683

Is there anyone who can give me a hint to handle correctly the COOKIES during applicationCache download event, without getting an error ?
Am I doing something wrong or against the standard ?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you make use of the localStorage instead of cookies?

Comment: Cookies are an environment shared between server and client while localStorage is only client-side.
I just need to understand why a session_start() call is an error for the application cache standard or if it's just a browser bug.

If it's an error for the standard I will try to use other solutions to evade calling session_start() while the file is being called by the appCache engine.